# pandas group dataframe until a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this code:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'col2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 'is_new_group': [True, False, False, True, False, False] }
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[image]

I would like to divide the data into groups.
Every group will start at the index of the first row where `is_new_group` is `True`, and end when a new `is_new_group`  is `True`

In this case, it should divide the data into 2 groups:
The first 3 rows, and the last 3 rows:
[image]
[image]

I found the `pd.groupby```.

according to the documentation, the `by` parameter: `mapping, function, label, or list of labels`.

But this is a different situation.

How can group the values according to the demands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `True` is the indicator of a new group, you can check where that is true and use `cumsum` to create your group labels.  That can be used to group on.

```
df.groupby(df.is_new_group.eq(True).cumsum())
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `cumsum` to detect every new `True`. In Python, `True` and `False` get converted to `1` and `0` respectively when performing calculations on them.

```
df.groupby(df.is_new_group.cumsum())
```

would do what you want.